# Finite Levy measure implies finite $L^1$ norm away from 0

Tags: probability, analysis

So I'm reading this paper on [Symmetrization of Levy processes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.1598.pdf) and I'm trying to wrap my head around a particular detail. Namely, on page 10, for the Levy density $\phi(x)$ with $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\frac{|x|^2}{1+|x|^2}\phi(x)dx<\infty$$
they introduce a function
$$\phi_n(x)=\phi(x)\mathbb{I}(x)$$
where $\mathbb{I}(x)$ is $1$ if $x\in\mathbb{R}^d\setminus B_{1/n}(0)$ and $0$ otherwise. Hence $\phi_n$ is simply $\phi(x)$ away from some ball of radius $1/n$ away from the origin 0 (so that $\mathbb{I}$ is simply an indicator function). They make the claim that from the above integral being finite, that:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\phi_n(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d\setminus B_{1/n}(0)}\phi(x)dx<\infty$$
I'm trying to figure out why that is the case. Thanks!

EDIT: You may assume $\phi\ge0$ here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that $\phi(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^d$. (I don't have full context here, but I think this is a safe bet.)

Note that
$$ x \in \mathbb R^d \setminus B_{1/n}(0) \implies \frac{|x|^2}{|x|^2 + 1} \geq \frac{1/n^2}{1/n^2 + 1}. $$

So
$$ \frac{1/n^2}{1/n^2 + 1}\times \int_{\mathbb{R}^d\setminus B_{1/n}(0)}\phi(x)dx \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^d\setminus B_{1/n}(0)} \frac{|x|^2}{|x|^2 + 1} \phi(x)dx \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \frac{|x|^2}{|x|^2 + 1} \phi(x)dx < \infty. $$

Hence
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d\setminus B_{1/n}(0)}\phi(x)dx  < \infty.$$

Comment: I figured the reasoning was something quick and easy (plus you can assume $\phi\ge0$ here; I'll mention that in the edit). Thanks!

Comment: cool, glad it helped